# How to automatically add list items based on all items in the drop-down column

Tags: server, 2019

I have the list with lookup drop-down column (name). The list is blank. I want to add automatically all items based on all drop-down column. Can you help me with this, please? Powershell, or some workflow?

Thanks a lot!